# how to create jquery mobile pinch zoom in and out

Tags: jquery, mobile, pinch

I have developed a jquery mobile application for android using Intel XDK. It's working fine but pinch zooming is not working even when I have changed Meta tag

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=2">
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: <div class="upage-content content-area vertical-col left">
                    <div class="widget uib_w_3 d-margins" data-uib="media/img" data-ver="0">                        
                        <!---     Text to Pinch zoom--> Text Area
                        
                    </div>
                </div>